# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, asynchronous

I use this code to load my JS async in the head

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 // Add a script element as a child of the body
 function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element4= document.createElement("script");
var element5= document.createElement("script");
element4.src="http:///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"
element5.src="http://yourjavascript.com/301810712121/slidemenu_horiz.js"
element4.async=true;
element5.async=true;
document.body.appendChild(element4);
document.body.appendChild(element5);
}
 // Check for browser support of event handling capability
 if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
 else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

In IE and Firefox works fine, but in Chrome I have this error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined "

When I refresh the page for second time (or third) the script works fine in Chrome, please I need to know how to resolve this.

Comment: if you are using jquery(document).ready event on your codes, it wont work, as jquery is not even ready at window.load, it's still pending downloading. since both are async, you wont know which will finish downloading first, if slidemenu_horiz.js finished downloading before jquery. It wont work as jquery wasn't ready by then... You might want to look into labjs or requirejs or steal.js for asynchronously loading ur js.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can I specified who finished first?

Comment: Why?  Why?  Why are you loading jQuery like this?  Why not use  `<script></script>` includes like every other site?  Just asking.

Answer (score 3):

Given your needs, and because I've used it successfully in the past I'd suggest using LABjs - http://labjs.com/

As mentioned, there are loads of script loaders to choose from - LABjs is focused on performance more than anything and doesn't include many of the extra features that others such as requirejs (AMD loader), YepNope (feature detection-based conditional loader) have. If all you need is to load your scripts asynchronously and have control over the execution order, LABjs is a very small script that handles this well.

Using LABjs, you'd do the following to replicate your code above:

```
<script src="js/libs/LAB.js"></script>
<script>
$LAB
.script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js').wait()
.script('http://yourjavascript.com/301810712121/slidemenu_horiz.js')
.wait(function () {
    // Check jQuery has loaded (could do this for the slider as well)
    if (window.jQuery) {
        // Do something with your slider
    }
});
</script>
```

In the example above, the `.wait()` function ensures that jQuery has executed before slidemenu_horiz.js - the last `.wait()` is passed an anonymous function as a callback - within this you can test that everything has loaded and then do your initialisations.

It's worth checking out all the options as far a script loaders go. There really are loads out there and each has a different feature set that you may find addresses your problem better.

**EDIT:** Added script reference to LABjs in code example for clarity